# what is this blank space that gets inserted in excel?

Tags: excel, formatting

When I open excel, the rows move down and a big blank space gets inserted. I have no idea why this is happening nor how to fix it. Any suggestions? See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[It's a known monitor issue, you have to check for compatibility](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/large-space-suddenly-appeared-between-formula-bar-amp-a1-help/m-p/195547)

If you drag it about between monitors it can fix it other than that compatibility settings.

Comment: Thank you Xyloz - I was not having any luck with searching for an answer :)